# Error in installing tensorfflow in python 3.11

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

(venv) PS C:\Users\Anushree Rajam\PycharmProjects\smartmusicplayer_main> pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
Using cached tensorflow-2.14.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (2.1 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-intel==2.14.0
Downloading tensorflow_intel-2.14.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (284.2 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╺━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 150.3/284.2 MB 569.9 kB/s eta 0:03:55
ERROR: Wheel 'tensorflow-intel' located at C:\Users\Anushree Rajam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-l_3dhdkt\tensorflow_intel-2.14.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl is invalid.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.2.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

I am trying to install tensorflow latest version in my new environment. But it is not installing and this 'tensorflow-intel' wheel is preventing which i am unclear about. My system is amd-ryzen-5. Is there any way i can prevent this?

Comment: If it's just the wheel in your cache that's bad, you can try to install with `pip install --no-cache-dir ..` to force pip to download the packages explicitly.

Comment: try this: `python -m pip install tensorflow`